# Custom module's configuration file in Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I am using Odoo 8 in ubuntu 14.04 environment. I installed a custom module with its config file which has some static values.

I am facing **File not found** error when need to load that config file.

The Addons path is resided outside of Odoo directory(i.e I was configured in odoo conf file)

```
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons
```

The module is resided in above location.

Previously, I get config file from odoo file directory using command..

> file_cfg = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(tools.config['root_path'],
>                '../openerp/addons/custom_module/custom_cfg.cfg'))

It does not work out. Hence I hardcoded the path in python file as

```
file_cfg = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/custom_module/custom_cfg.cfg'
```

**How do I get the config file programmatically ?**

Please give a suggestion...

Comment: file_cfg = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(tools.config['root_path'], '../odoo/addons/custom_module/custom_cfg.cfg')) try this

Comment: @Jainik ll try and update soon

Comment: Thanks a lot... It is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
file_cfg = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(tools.config['root_path'], '../odoo/addons/custom_module/custom_cfg.cfg'))
```